# Multiple RecyclerViews in same layout: Click listener for one gets triggered for all recyclerViews

Tags: java, android

I have two recyclerViews (say A and B) in the same layout that have an adapter which for both the recyclerViews look like this:

---

```
public class ChapterListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ChapterListAdapter.ChapterListViewHolder>{

private final ArrayList<ChapterObj> mChapterListObj;
private final Context mContext;

public ChapterListAdapter(ArrayList<ChapterObj> chapterObj, Context c) {
    mChapterListObj = chapterObj;
    mContext = c;
}

@Override
public ChapterListViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.chapter_list_item, parent, false);
    ChapterListViewHolder vh = new ChapterListViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ChapterListViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.chapterNumber.setText(mChapterListObj.get(position).getChapterNumber());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mChapterListObj.size();
}

public class ChapterListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnTouchListener {
    private TextView chapterNumber;

    public ChapterListViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        chapterNumber = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.chapter_number);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        itemView.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d("hello", "hello");
        }
    }

}
}
```

Both A and B have click listeners. Independently, both work fine. But when both are in the same layout, whenever I click on an item of 'A', the click listener of 'B' gets triggered.

If you need to see more code, tell me which file you want to see, I'll add their code too.

---

Edit: The xml layout file in which I've used them together looks like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".VerseActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/chapter_list_menu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/verse_list_menu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Since you are declaring `android:layout_height="match_parent"` in your first RecyclerView and `android:layout_width="match_parent"` in the second one, you will be sure that the two RecylcerViews will be overlapped. Moreover consider that the layout_height attribute allow wrap_content only if you are using at least [The Android support library 23.2.1](http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html)

Comment: You're right, but only a small part will overlap won't it? I can see that overlapping part in the result. I'm not clicking on that part. Anywhere I click on both 'A' and 'B', the click listener for only 'B' gets triggered. But I'll give them both 'wrap_content' and separate them as much as I can and give it a try again.

Comment: Yes, but your listener is on the whole RecyclerView. It doesn't metter what item you click on. If you want to trigger an action when a particoular item is clicked you should set a clickListener on the view itemView (it is a view in the RecyclerView that represent the whole row layout)

Comment: Well, first I updated the support library and recyclerView library's versions from 23.1.1 to 23.3.0, 
and then I played around with heights and widths of the recyclerView items and voila, it works fine now :)
Thanks brother :) The issue was with the height and width itself, but although I was already setting click listener to the itemView, I've shared the adapter's code in question. Have I done it the way it's supposed to be so that it triggers on item being clicked or I missed something?

Well anyway it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

You can do same thing with Sectioned recycler view. which will even load faster and let you display as many sectioned as you want. (removes hurdle of 2-3 recyclerview in same page or view)

If you want to create your own you can check this - https://gist.github.com/gabrielemariotti/4c189fb1124df4556058

or you can find many libraries for that also.